# Как "вытянуть" свойство класса из css в js? (react)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, модули

В общем мне нужно, чтобы при значении height: 0 у класса "screen" div с этим классом удалялся вместе с его содержимым. Я хотел задать условие через if, но не знаю как из css файла "вытянуть" значение height, да и собственно как div удалять в реакте я не знаю, помогите пожалуйста, я честно говоря только учусь.. Спасибо!

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import classes from './style.module.css';

class Screen extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      swipe: " "
    }
    this.handleSwipe = this.handleSwipe.bind(this);
  }

  handleSwipe(){
    this.setState({swipe: classes.swiper});
  }

  render(){
    return <div className={classes.screen + " " + this.state.swipe}>
        <img className={classes.screen__image} src={this.props.screenImage} alt="wallpaper" />
        <div className={classes.screen__swiper} onClick={this.handleSwipe}></div>
    </div>
  }
}
export default Screen;
```

```css
.screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    left: 23px;
    width: 314px;
    height: 678px;
    z-index: 50;
}
.screen__image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.screen__swiper{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 314px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 50;
    background: #fff;
}

.swiper {
    height: 0px;
    filter: blur(5px);
    transition: all 10s ease-in;
}

/* .swipe {
    animation: 3s swipe;
}
@keyframes swipe {
0% {transform: translate(0,720px);}
100% {transform: translate(0,-100px);}
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А на простом js знаете как это делается?

Comment: для удаления div'a я переписал handleSwipe добавил аргумент e и добавил строку e.target.parentNode.remove(); но, чтобы было условие, мне надо поймать значение height

Comment: в простом js получать значение любого свойcтва у элементов на странице можно через getpropertyvalue https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue

Comment: e.target.parentNode.style.getPropertyValue('height'); возвращает в консоли мне пустую строку

Comment: Возьмите у любого элемента свойства на странице на простом js, а потом сделайте это в реакте. `window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).padding` - как это делается в js, чтобы взять свойства padding у body. Я так брал свойства, возможно, можно и по другому

Comment: Ой, извините, я ошибся в названии, они похожи, я в первых комментариях неправильно вам написал как получить свойства, это было проверить. https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes тут про `getComputedStyle` написано

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!